# GCP Pub/Sub Deadline Exceeded while creating publisher or topic

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

so I'm starting to get more and more of those while resolving my `Publisher`:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="Deadline Exceeded", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1641224884.231133843","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.212.170:443","file":"/var/local/git/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}")

Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="DeadlineExceeded", Detail="Deadline Exceeded", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1641224884.231133843","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.212.170:443","file":"/var/local/git/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}")
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
   at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at My.Messaging.Publisher`1..ctor(IOptions`1 pubSubOptions)
```

here is my `Publisher` constructor:

```cs
public Publisher(IOptions<PubSubOptions> pubSubOptions)
        {
            var projectName = pubSubOptions.Value.GcpProjectName;
            
            TopicName topicName = new TopicName(projectName, typeof(T).Name);
            PublisherServiceApiClient client;
            
            var client = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create();
            
            try
            {
                client.CreateTopic(topicName);
            }
            catch (RpcException e) when (e.Status.StatusCode == StatusCode.AlreadyExists)
            {
                //it's ok
                //_logger.LogDebug($"Topic {topicName} already exists.");
            }

            this.publisher = PublisherClient.Create(topicName);
        }
```

This code is working, but from time to time it gives me deadlines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CreateTopic has a deadline of one minute. Have you timed the code to see how long it's actually taking, both when working and when not working? Are there any unusual aspects of your networking which might cause this? (We don't have any context for where this code is running.)

Comment: sorry, everything is hosted on GCP in one region. 
I've moved this code from ctor to the actual Publish method and added retry logic, since then it's working ok.